# For...in loop not returning values from JSON object list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using a for...in loop to write the values inside a JSON data set into an unordered list on a webpage.

When the code below is executed I only get one list item element with all of the objects in the JSON data inside, rather than a single list item for each object. The values of the objects in the JSON data are also not being written to the list item elements.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <ul id="test">
    </ul>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="doer_json.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$.getJSON('doer_data.json', function(data) {            
for (key in data) {
    $('#test').append("<li>" + data[key] + "</li>");
} // for loop 

$('#test li').css("color", "blue"); });
```

JSON data:

```
{ "list" : 
            [
                {"todo": "Complete remaining Duckett chapters."},
                {"todo": "Watch AngularJs video on Lynda.com."},
                {"todo": "Complete design specification for Doer app."},
                {"todo": "Complete play."},
                {"todo": "Finish Flatland."},
                {"todo": "Finish Harper's"}

            ]}
```

Interestingly when using `data[key].todo` in the `.append()` method, I was able to retrieve the values of the JSON objects and add them to the unordered list successfully.Yesterday. Today this code is not working. So I either did it incorrectly yesterday or something else is causing this code not to perform correctly.

Answer (score 6):

The data you're trying to loop over is in the `list` array, therefore you need to amend your code to use a `for` loop with an incrementing index variable, and loop over `data.list`, not just `data`. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
    $('#test').append("<li>" + data.list[i].todo + "</li>");
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fj2xhmod/)

Answer (score 0):

for...in loops are not for iterating over arrays. They are only for iterating over the properties of objects.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `$.getJSON` returns a deferred promise so you could do this:

```
$.getJSON('doer_data.json') 
 .done(function(data){
      data.list.forEach(function(i){
          $("#test").append("<li>" + i.todo + "</li>")
      });
 })
 .fail(function(xhr){ console.log("fail " + xhr.responseText)});
```

Or for looping it like Rory (but caching the data length) :P

```
len = myArray.length; i < len

$.getJSON('doer_data.json') 
 .done(function(data){
      for(var i = 0, len = data.list.length; i < len; i++){
          $("#test").append("<li>" + data.list[i].todo + "</li>")
      }
 })
 .fail(function(xhr){ console.log("fail " + xhr.responseText)});
```